# Splitting a weighted graph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Consider a weighted graph:

```
g=Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 2 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 4},EdgeWeight -> {0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 6, 9}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"];

g1 = FindGraphPartition[g]
g2 = HighlightGraph[g, Map[Subgraph[g, #] &, g1]]
```

How to determine data for red/yellow weighted graph.
Example of Answers:

```
g3={{1 <-> 2, 0}, {2 <-> 3, 3}, {3 <-> 1, 4}}
```

I need to do this for large graphs
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematica 12.0 and later, you can use

```
PropertyValue[
 Subgraph[g, g1[[2]]],
 EdgeWeight
]
```

In earlier versions, use `IGWeightedSubgraph` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) instead of `Subgraph`, as `Subgraph` would discard weights.

With IGraph/M, you can also use `IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight][graph]` to extract edge weights.